# How and why does Wilhelm win against Theresia?

Tags: re-zero

So we know that Reinhard is brokenly overpowered with all the blessings he has. 
(A google of "re zero reinhard blessings" will bring up a fair number of sources describing roughly the same list.)

Even if we assume that his grandmother Theresia only had the Sword Saint one "Sword Saint: Swordsmanship maxes out, and become able to draw Raid, the Dragon Sword.".

How does Wilhelm defeat her in a sword fight as witnessed in the anime, before they sort of become a couple. Does the light novel or web novel shed more light on this?

Or did Wilhelm seriously outfight the sword saint in a sword fight? I assume she still had at least the sword saint blessing, as their grandchild Reinhard didn't exist yet to take the blessing from her yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by character [synopsis on Wiki](http://rezero.wikia.com/wiki/Wilhelm_van_Astrea/Synopsis), it was not covered by all. He simply left during Demi-Humans War, and then returned and defeated Theresia.

One thing - I'm not sure, that Divine Blessing of Sword Saint gives its owner *perfect* swordsman skills. I suppose, Theresia only had certain fixed swordsman skill level, obtained by blessing. But Wilhelm spent years for training and a lots of effort to gain his skills. So, it is not that strange, that, if taking into account only swordsmanship skills, it was possible for ordinary human to overcome Sword Saint in duel. Maybe, if Theresia were to use any of other her blessings, she would defeat Wilhelm.